# CursorAdapter MemoryLeak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-cursoradapter

**UPDATE:**
I solved my problem but couldn't figure it out what was causing it. I discovered that the issue was on the AsyncTask that Queried the db. I dropped the class and implemented a CursorLoader. Sayonara Memory Leak.
I'm maintaining the question, since I couldn't discover what was causing the problem.

I checked my Activity and my Adapter multiple times and couldn't find the infamous Leak. I analyzed the dumb in MAT and come to the conclusion that the Leak is in the ImageView of the ItemHolder and probably in the Adapter. I'm not very familiar with MAT and could't advance more.

I tried everything (at least I think so). WeakReferences, EventBus, cleaning Data, but still the Leak persists, and since I'm dealing with multiple ImageViews the problem is huge.

Thanks!

**Activity**

```
public class PhotoListActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private static final String TAG = "PhotoListActivity";

private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAP  = 111;

private String              mCurrentPhotoPath;
private CoordinatorLayout   coordinatorLayout;
private ProgressBar         progressBar;

private GridView grid;
private GridAdapter gridAdapter;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    gridAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    grid = null;
    gridAdapter = null;
    if ( loadPhotos != null )
    {
        if ( loadPhotos.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING )
            loadPhotos.cancel( true );
        loadPhotos = null;
    }
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if ( loadPhotos != null )
    {
        if ( loadPhotos.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING )
            loadPhotos.cancel( true );
        loadPhotos = null;
    }

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_list);

    coordinatorLayout   = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorlayout);
    progressBar         = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loader);

    gridAdapter         = new GridAdapter(this, null);
    grid                = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    grid.setAdapter( gridAdapter);

    // Loading Photos
    loadPhotos();

    if ( savedInstanceState != null )
    {
        alarmSet = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_ALARM);
        alarmCanceled   = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_CANCELED);
    }
    if ( !alarmCanceled )
        setAlarm();

}

private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;
private Intent mNotificationReceiverIntent;
private PendingIntent mNotificationReceiverPendingIntent;
private static final long INITIAL_ALARM_DELAY = 2 * 60 * 1000L;

private boolean alarmSet;
private boolean alarmCanceled;

private void setAlarm()
{
    mAlarmManager   = (AlarmManager) getSystemService( ALARM_SERVICE );

    mNotificationReceiverIntent = new Intent(
            getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class
    );
    mNotificationReceiverPendingIntent  = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getApplicationContext(), 0, mNotificationReceiverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
    );

    // Set repeating Alarm
    mAlarmManager.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis(),
            INITIAL_ALARM_DELAY,
            mNotificationReceiverPendingIntent
    );
    alarmSet    = true;
    alarmCanceled = false;

    Log.d(TAG, "Alarm set");

}

private void cancelAlarm()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "Alarm Canceled");

    mAlarmManager.cancel(mNotificationReceiverPendingIntent);
    alarmSet = false;
    alarmCanceled = true;
    Snackbar.make(
            coordinatorLayout,
            "Alarm Canceled", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    setAlarm();
                }
            }).show();
}


QueryPhotos loadPhotos;
private void loadPhotos()
{
    loadPhotos = new QueryPhotos(new WeakReference<Context>(getApplicationContext()));
    loadPhotos.execute();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // save and process photo
    if ( requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAP && resultCode == RESULT_OK )
    {
        // save image on DB
        saveCurrentPhoto();
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

/**
 * Insert photo taken in the DB
 */
private void saveCurrentPhoto()
{
    String photoName    = mCurrentPhotoPath.substring(mCurrentPhotoPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    String photoDate    = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());

    mCurrentPhotoPath   = null;
}

/**
 * Receive call from InsertPhoto onPostExecute
 * @param id    New photo DB record
 */
public void photoInserted(long id) {
    Log.d(TAG, "DB Photo ID " + id );
    // TODO update List

    // Feedback user
    Snackbar
            .make(coordinatorLayout, "Photo Saved! ID: " + id, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_photo_list, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if ( alarmSet )
    {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_cancelalarm).setEnabled(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_setalarm).setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_cancelalarm).setEnabled(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_setalarm).setEnabled(true);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch ( id ) {
        case R.id.action_photo: {
            takePicture();
            return true;
        }
        case R.id.action_setalarm: {
            setAlarm();
            return true;
        }
        case R.id.action_cancelalarm:
            cancelAlarm();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private static final String STATE_ALARM = "state_alarm";
private static final String STATE_CANCELED  = "alarm_canceled";
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(STATE_ALARM, alarmSet );
    outState.putBoolean( STATE_CANCELED, alarmCanceled );
}

/**
 * Open a Photo App and return the result
 */
private void takePicture() {
    Intent takePicIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if ( takePicIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null )
    {
        File imageFile  = createPhotoFile();
        if ( imageFile != null ) {
            takePicIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePicIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAP);
        }

    }
}

/**
 * Create a File image with a safe name
 * @return  File obj to save the Photo
 */
private File createPhotoFile() {
    String timeStamp     = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPG_" + timeStamp;


    String externalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File storageDir = new File(externalStorage + "/DailySelfie");
    if ( !storageDir.exists() )
        storageDir.mkdir();
    try {
        File imageFile  = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,
                ".jpg",
                storageDir
        );
        mCurrentPhotoPath    = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();

        return imageFile;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error createPhotoFile e:" + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

}


private void openDetail(int id, int position)
{
    Intent openDetail   = new Intent(PhotoListActivity.this, DetailActivity.class );
    openDetail.putExtra( DetailActivity.EXTRA_POSITION, position);
    startActivity( openDetail );
}


public void onEvent(QueryPhotos.QueryEvent queryEvent) {
    gridAdapter.swapCursor(queryEvent.getCursor());
}
public void onEvent(QueryPhotos.ProgressbarStatus visible) {
    if ( visible.isVisible() )
    {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}

public void onEvent(SelfiesAdapter.OnSelfieClick selfieClick) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onSelfieClick selfie id: " + selfieClick.getSelfie().getId());
    // TODO Open Photo detail
    openDetail(  selfieClick.getSelfie().getId(), selfieClick.getPosition() );
}

public void onEvent(final SelfiesAdapter.OnSelfieLongClick selfieLongClick ) {
    final Selfie selfie = selfieLongClick.getSelfie();
    Log.d(TAG, "onSelfieLongClick selfie id: " + selfie.getId() );
    // open dialog to delete Selfie
    final AlertDialog.Builder deleteSelfie    = new AlertDialog.Builder( this );
    deleteSelfie.setTitle( "Do you want to delete Selfie " + selfie.getId() + " ?");
    deleteSelfie.setMessage(
            "Photo taken " + selfie.getDate()
    );
    deleteSelfie.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Delete Selfie
            Log.d(TAG, " Delete Selfie " + selfie.getId());
           /* DeleteSelfie delete = new DeleteSelfie( selfie, selfieLongClick.getPosition() );
            delete.execute();*/
        }
    });

    deleteSelfie.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    deleteSelfie.create().show();
}
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class GridAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private static final String TAG = "GridAdapter";

private static class ViewHolder {
    private ImageView imgThumb;
    private TextView txtName;
    private ProgressBar loader;
    private RelativeLayout container;
}

private LayoutInflater inflater;

public GridAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public GridAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
    super(context, c, autoRequery);
}

public GridAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
}


@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    final Selfie selfie = new Selfie(cursor, cursor.getPosition());
    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.txtName.setText(selfie.getName());

    // create thumbnail
    final ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    final ImageLoadingListener imageLoadingListener = new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            holder.imgThumb.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
            holder.loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ((ImageView) view).setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

        }
    };
    imageLoader.displayImage(
            "file://" + selfie.getPath(),
            holder.imgThumb,
            null,
            imageLoadingListener,
            null);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, final Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewholder_photolist, null);

    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.container = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);
    holder.imgThumb = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
    holder.txtName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
    holder.loader = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.loader);

    itemView.setTag(holder);

    return itemView;
}
}
```

**QueryPhotos**

```
public class QueryPhotos extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor>
{
private static final String TAG = "QueryPhotos";

private DBSchema mDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private String[]        cols = {
        DBSchema.TB_PHOTO.ID,
        DBSchema.TB_PHOTO.NAME,
        DBSchema.TB_PHOTO.PATH_FULL,
        DBSchema.TB_PHOTO.DATE_CREATED
};
private String          orderBy = DBSchema.TB_PHOTO.ID +" ASC";

public QueryPhotos( WeakReference<Context> context ) {
    mDBHelper   = new DBSchema(context.get());
    db          = mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();

}

@Override
protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        publishProgress();

        return db.query( DBSchema.TABLE_PHOTOS,cols, null, null, null, null, orderBy, null );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "LoadPhotos query error e:" + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    // Loader
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new ProgressbarStatus(false));
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) {
    if ( null != cursor )
    {
        // Realod Photo List
        Log.d(TAG, "LoadPhotos done");

        // TODO result via Event.Bus
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new ProgressbarStatus(false));
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new QueryEvent(cursor));
    }

    super.onPostExecute(cursor);
}

public class QueryEvent {
    private Cursor cursor;

    public Cursor getCursor() {
        return cursor;
    }

    public QueryEvent(Cursor cursor) {
        this.cursor = cursor;
    }
}

public class ProgressbarStatus {
    private boolean visible;

    public boolean isVisible() {
        return visible;
    }

    public ProgressbarStatus(boolean visible) {
        this.visible = visible;
    }
}
}
```

**MAT Analysis**
[image: Problem Suspect]

**Dominator tree**
[image: Dominator Tree]

**Path to GC Roots excluding WeakReferences**
[image]

Comment: why do u think the programm have memory leak?

Comment: The App calls a Notification. When I click on the notification this Activity shows again. When I repeat this process the MemoryAlocation keep increasing, even with a forced GC dump, until a OOM occur. EDIT: When I test in a device the problem is very noticeable

Comment: The MAT also show a lot of ImageViews and Bitmaps duplicated.

Comment: Are you properly using all the drawable folders? It could be that an asset is being upscaled from xhdpi to xxhdpi for example, repeatedly through your adapter...

Comment: I believe so. In fact I'm loading Bitmaps from the SD Cards. The only resource that I'm using is a sound and its related to the notification.

Comment: why are you extending `CursorAdapter`? why not `ResourceCursorAdapter`, or even `SimpleCursorAdapter` ?

Comment: For no special reason. As a matter of fact I never used ResourceCursorAdapter and the SimpleCursorAdapter doesn't fit well for my needs. Did u saw any problems with the adapter implementation?

Comment: I still don't know where the problem was, but I dropped the AsyncTask and implemented a ContentProvider and CursorLoader to query the DB. Works just fine now.